# Split View Controller - Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to add a custom UITableViewCell to my Split View Controller Master. When I run my app the cells don't appear, although they do carry the information as confirmed by a println statement. After some research I found out that only standard UITableViewCells are generated.

The Table ViewController has the Data Source and Delegate connected via the Storyboard and the UITableViewCell has a custom Class with Identifier.

The TableView & TableViewCell are in the same ViewController.

The TableViewCell reusable identifier is "ArtistCell" and it's class is ArtistCell.

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ArtistsMasterTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var artistsQuery:MPMediaQuery!
    var artists:NSArray!
    var artistAlbums:NSArray!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        artistsQuery = MPMediaQuery.artistsQuery()
        artists = artistsQuery.collections
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return artists.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println(artists[indexPath.row].items)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ArtistCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ArtistCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        var rowItem:MPMediaItem = artists.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).representativeItem

        if let artwork = rowItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork) as? MPMediaItemArtwork {
            cell.artistImage!.image = artwork.imageWithSize(cell.artistImage.bounds.size)
        }

        cell.artistNameLabel.text = rowItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtist) as? String
        //        artistCell.albumsLabel.text = rowItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtist) as? String
        //        artistCell.songsLabel.text = rowItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtist) as? String

        return cell

}
```

The custom cell:

```
class ArtistCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var artistImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var artistNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var albumsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var songsLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Here are some Storyboard screenshots:
[image: The Table View]

[image: The Outlets Inspector]

[image: The Attributes Inspector]

[image: The Storyboard hierarchy]

Comment: Did you design the cell as a prototype cell of your table view in the same storyboard file?

Comment: Yes, the cell is a prototype and is in the same storyboard.

Comment: Are they also in the same ViewController?

Comment: Yes both the Table View and Table View Cell are in the same ViewController.

Comment: Check your cell's reuse id in IB, is it `ArtistCell`?

Comment: Yes the reusable identifier is indeed ArtistCell

Comment: Then maybe you haven't set cells custom class? set a breakpoint into cellForRowAtIndexPath, what class does cell have?

Comment: The cell has the custom class ArtistCell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question.  From what I've seen the way to implement this is to create a custom xib file that you dequeue.  Here is the best article on the subject in objective-c: https://medium.com/@musawiralishah/creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-nib-xib-files-in-xcode-9bee5824e722

Essentially, you do the following:

1. Setup your table just like you have minus the reusable cell
2. Create a custom xib file and make it look like your prototype cell (you can simply do this by making an empty object and dragging a tableviewcell onto the storyboard

[image]

3. Make sure to set the class type of the xib to ArtistCell in the Identity Inspector

[image]

4. Create a custom class ArtistCell to hook the xib up to

[image]

5. Use this code when you are setting up your cellForRowAtIndexPath

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? ArtistCell

   if cell == nil{
       tableView .registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ArtistCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
       cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? ArtistCell
   }

   cell?.nameLabel.text = "Hello World"

   return cell!
   }
   ```

Here's a screen cap just in case:

[image]

This code has been fully tested and works for me. FYI. :-) Hope this helps!

Cheers!
Rob Norback